# Add Attribute in existing NSMutableAttributed String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, strikethrough

I'm working on some attributed string format. I need to add strike out into existing NSMutableAttributed String. Is it possible in below given example.

```
First Task For Bhasin
30 Jun 2017 12:05 PM till 30 Jun 2017 01:05 PM{
NSBackgroundColor = "<CGColor 0x6100000934c0> [<CGColorSpace 0x6080000303c0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome; Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile; extended range)] ( 0 0 )";
NSColor = "<CGColor 0x6180002a2ac0> [<CGColorSpace 0x610000230920> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1; extended range)] ( 1 0 0 1 )";
NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fac5476a0b0> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt";
NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}
```

Comment: Add the code of `attributedString`

Comment: @Subramanian, i'm using DAAttributedStringFormatter. I want to add strike out there

Comment: Add the answer to convert `NSAttributedString` to `NSMutableAttributedString` and adding the strike through attribute.

Comment: And what have you tried? What's your code ? Did you look for answers on StackOverFlow? Because I think that it should already have an answer.

Comment: Well the issue is the the code uses DAAttributedStringFormatter, and other issue is the NSConcreteMutableAttributedString where i'm not able to add another attribute.

Answer (score 9):

`attributedString` is the existing `NSMutableAttributedString`.

**Objective C**

**Convert `NSAttributedString` to `NSMutableAttributedString`**

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:<#Your String Here#>];
```

Add `Strikethrough` Attribute

```
 [attributedString addAttributes:@{ NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]} range:NSMakeRange(x, y)];
```

**x  = Starting index, y = length of the string.**

**Swift :**

```
 attributedString.addAttributes([NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: NSNumber(integer: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue)], range: NSMakeRange(x, y))
```

**Convert `NSAttributedString` to `NSMutableAttributedString`**

```
 let attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: <#NSAttributedString#>)
```

Comment: Already added. And tag your question to Objective c. So it will help the people to identify the preferred language.